# What guarantees are given by SMB and EXT3 regarding order of file writes?

Tags: filesystems, samba, ext3

From my (Linux-)application, I am watching a hotfolder for specific sets of files. For example, I am waiting for this set:

- example-1.xml
- example-2.xml
- example-3.xml

The hotfolder is shared over the network via SMB. Now, to be sure that all files are written before I move them away, I will wait for one last empty file:

- example.done

My client will ensure that this file will be the last file that is written.

My assumptions are:

- files will be sent over the network and stored on disk in the order they were written.
- once the example.done file is available, all previous files will be complete.

Are these assumptions correct?

Searching for "file system guarantees" only results in explanations of in-file ordering or reliability in system crashes:
[Guarantees of order of the operations on file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463925/guarantees-of-order-of-the-operations-on-file)
[Does Linux guarantee the contents of a file is flushed to disc after close()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705454/does-linux-guarantee-the-contents-of-a-file-is-flushed-to-disc-after-close)
[What reliability guarantees are provided by NTFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129205/what-reliability-guarantees-are-provided-by-ntfs)

Comment: What SMB clients/servers would this be with?

Comment: The SMB server is Samba, the client is Windows (XP and up). But I hope this shouldn't matter.